# Publish date, managers and relations

Tags: python, django

Consider the following models:

```
class Artist(GalleryMixin, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Exhibition(GalleryMixin, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_(u'title'))
    artists = models.ManyToManyField('Artist')
```

Now, I added a `publish_on` `DateTimeField` and I don't want to see any objects
on the website with `publish_date` superior to `datetime.datetime.now()`, so I
made a manager (using [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#manager-types)) and it looks like this:

```
class PublicObjectManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get_query_set(self):
        qs = super(PublicObjectManager, self).get_query_set()
        qs = qs.filter(publish_on__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
        return qs


class Artist(GalleryMixin, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    publish_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    public_objects = PublicObjectManager()
    objects = models.Manager()


class Exhibition(GalleryMixin, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_(u'title'))
    artists = models.ManyToManyField('Artist')
    publish_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    public_objects = PublicObjectManager()
    objects = models.Manager()
```

This works great: non-published objects never appear on the website... But admins are not be able to see non-published objects
! So I could override the admin queryset of course, but it would be hard to
override **relations** querysets which means that admins could not use `Select`
fields to create relations to non-published objects.

Ie. **admin would not be able to select a non-published Artist in Exhibition.artists.**

What's your take on this ?

Comment: If I see your point, you might just want to remove the `use_for_related_fields` from the manager.

Comment: Ok, but then in the website, `{{ exhibition.artists.all }}` will return **non published** artists.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this by just writing a method on the base object rather than using managers (to me it's more readable than having to remember about 'hidden' base manager changes):

```
class Exhibition(GalleryMixin, models.Model):
  ...
  def publishedArtists(self):
    return self.artist_set.filter(publish_on__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Then in your template you could just do:

```
   {{exhibition.publishedArtists}}
```

Comment: Yes of course, but the advantage of the manager is that it is used with prefetch_related() and friends which is way cool ...